# How to get transaction amount from another android app

Tags: android, square-connect

I'd like to redirect the user from my android app to square app so he or she completes the payment transaction, then I need the paid amount to keep in my android app. You can assume that the user has already installed square app and can use it standalone.

Currently I can create a charge and pass it but I'd like the user to enter payment amount within the square app.

Ideally would be great to get the amount from the intent result like:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == Constants.CHARGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (data == null) {
            showDialog("Error", "Square Point of Sale was uninstalled or crashed", null);
            return;
        }

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            ChargeRequest.Success success = posClient.parseChargeSuccess(data);
            String message = "Client transaction id: " + success.clientTransactionId;
            showDialog("Success!", message, null);
```

But don't know how to get the amount from the intend data...

Comment: You can use implicit intent

Comment: Thanks @RohitChauhan can you tell me how to get the amount from intent data?

Answer (score 0):

The ChargeRequest.Success has two fields: clientTransactionId and serverTransactionId. (see: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/point-of-sale/android/com/squareup/sdk/pos/ChargeRequest.Success.html)

Using the serverTransactionId you can call the RetrieveTransactions endpoint: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-retrievetransaction if you need to look up information about the transaction (such as the amount).